# Tomcat not respecting showReport="false" parameter in server.xml

Tags: tomcat, webserver, tomcat9

I am deploying an application using Tomcat 9.0.65 in my Red Hat 7.9 environment. Although the Tomcat service starts and I can access my application through the browser, Tomcat is not respecting the showReport="false" parameter set in the server.xml file.

When I run the command **curl -vL http://127.0.0.1:8090/application-name/qm/application-name/img/logo.xhtml?unity=%2F***, the response is shown in the image below:

[curl_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tzYy.jpg)

Here is the configuration of my server.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8090" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve"/>
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"
             showReport="false"
             showServerInfo="false"/>
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

I have already tried reinstalling Tomcat, modifying the server.xml file, and checking the web.xml, context.xml, and catalina.properties files, but the problem still persists. Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?